Inserting files with PreparedStatements vs batch with PreparedStatements
I am doing performance tests inserting records in a MySQL DB. I thought that using PreparedStatements with batches would be more efficient than simply using PreparedStatemens (as stated at Efficient way to do batch INSERTS with JDBC). However, with a different number of records, I get that the PreparedStatement-only version is more efficient.
For example, with 21800 records I get the times:

4093 with batch and PreparedStatement
3932 only with PreparedStatement

I can't understand why with PreparedStatement it is faster. Any idea?

how large is your batch size? the optimal size depends on the size of the inserted data. try with different sizes.
